# jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JS that I am not OK with.  How can I reduce the amount of code?

```js
(function ($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion-modal > dd').hide();
    $('.firstlink').addClass('green');
    $('.firstlink > header').addClass('green');
    $('.accordion-modal > .active-accordian').show();
    $('.active-accordian').addClass('.active');
    $('.accordion-modal > dt > a').click(function () {
        $(this).children('header').addClass('green');
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').children('header').removeClass('green'); //$(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('green');
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="accordion-modal">

    <dt><a  href=""><header class='firstlink'>FIRST</header></a></dt>
            <dd class="active-accordian">FIRST CONTENT</dd>

<dt><a href=""><header>SECOND</header></a></dt>
<dd>SECOND CONTENT</dd>


</dl>
```

Comment: Was the answer below helpful? Any follow up?

Comment: Txanks, but i still thinks it can be shorter :(

Answer (score 1):

You could clean a lot of the code just by caching your selectors and chaining them where appropriate. This will improve performance as well. Also some of this code should be after the `document.ready` event to make sure the DOM elements are available to be manipulated.  Dividing up your functionality into several smaller functions will help with debugging later on.

```
(function ($) {

  var modal, allPanels;

  function setActive( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    var $t = $(e.target);    
    modal.find('.green').removeClass('green');  //remove existing class
    $t.children('header').addClass('green');
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $t.parent().next().slideDown();
  }

  function init() {
    modal.find('.firstlink').addClass('green')
         .find('header').addClass('green').end().end()
         .find('.active-accordian').show().addClass('.active').end()
         .find('dt').on('click','a', setActive);
  }

  $(function() {
    modal = $('.accordion-modal');
    allPanels = modal.find('dd').hide();
    init();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you explained in the comments you are looking for **something shorter**. With that in mind, I completely re-wrote your javascript code to be much simpler and much more concise.

First off, if you can modify the HTML it would make life a lot simpler.  To make an accordion, all your really need is this:

```
<dl class="accordion-modal">
  <dt>FIRST</dt>
  <dd>FIRST CONTENT</dd>
  <dt>SECOND</dt>
  <dd>SECOND CONTENT</dd>
</dl>
```

Then when you are ready to show the `dd` content, you can just do `$(this).next().slideDown()` to show the area when the `dt` is clicked.

FYI: I changed to a simple `active` class in the examples.  Here is the adjusted code:

```
(function( $ ) {

  $(function() {
    var $acc = $('.accordion-modal');
    var $dd = $acc.find('dd');
    var $dt = $acc.find('dt');

    $dd.hide().first().addClass('active').show(); //hide all, show 1st, add class
    $dt.first().addClass('active'); //add active class

    $acc.on('click','dt', function() {
       $dd.slideUp().removeClass('active');
       $dt.removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown().addClass('active');
    });
  });

})( jQuery );
```

First we encapsulate the code in an IIFE, then on `document.ready`, we get are selections and add our `click` event.

Now, if you can't change the HTML, you can still use this code with some slight modification:

```
$(function(){
    var $acc = $('.accordion-modal');
    var $dd = $acc.find('dd');
    var $dt = $acc.find('dt');        

    $dd.hide().first().addClass('active').show();
    $dt.first().addClass('active');

    $acc.on('click','header', function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();           
       $dd.slideUp().removeClass('active');
       $dt.removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active').parents('dt').next().slideDown().addClass('active');
    });

});
```

The only real difference is we have to get the parent `dt` element first.
I have created two fiddles.  For the first option, you can [use this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oo6e1zho/3/) and the second one is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ekdcrb/5/).

Hope that helps.